# Comment Pagination Error

Tags: pagination, comments

I looked at the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/comment/) and it seemed to me that the way comments tag do pagination is the same as channel entries tag.

```
{exp:comment:entries
    entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"
    {if embed:limit}limit="{embed:limit}"{/if}
    paginate="hidden"
    {if embed:sort}sort="{embed:sort}"{/if}
}
...
{/exp:comment:entries}
```

So I tried accessing the page that displays the comments

```
http://domain.com/foo/750/abc/P10
```

segment 2 = entry_id
segment 3 = title
segment 4 = pagination item

However, I see this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Functions::remove_double_slashes() in .../system/expressionengine/modules/comment/mod.comment.php on line 3324
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I suggest checking line 3324 in mod.comment.php as a first step. Are you able to track things backwards?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it seems to be a deprecated function. But if so, then why does 2.8.1 still include it?